# Entity Framework not saving to the database

Tags: entity-framework

I have a challenge that I am trying to update a record from database But it is not saving to the database, and not showing any errors, it is giving a message that it has updated the record but there are no changes to the database. My code is as below. Any suggestions

```
dbEntities context = new dbEntities();

var query = context.ConsultantsProfiles.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Username == username);

        if (query != null)
        { 

          query.Summary = txtSummary.Text;
          query.CareerTitle = txtTitle.Text;
          query.ConsultantType = cbType.Text;
          query.Username = username;
          query.FirstName = txtFirstname.Text;
          query.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
          query.Email = txtEmail.Text;
          query.DateofBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dptDateofBirth.Value);
          query.PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
          query.Website = txtWebsite.Text;
          query.Town = txtTown.Text;
          query.Country = txtCountry.Text;

          if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
          {
            //image upload
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
            // HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadControl.UploadedFiles[i];
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] imgByte = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            int imglength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

            query.ProfilePhoto = imgByte;

          }



          context.ConsultantsProfiles.Attach(query);
          context.Entry(query).State = EntityState.Modified;
          context.SaveChanges();
        }
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Notification: The Profile Has been Updated');</script>");
        }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? For instance, you have a whole block that gets excluded when `query == null`. Have you checked whether that might be the case? Or have you monitored your database queries to see what got executed? Or something else that might give you any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbEntities context = new dbEntities();
var consultantProfile = new ConsultantProfile
{
    Summary = txtSummary.Text;
    CareerTitle = txtTitle.Text;
    ConsultantType = cbType.Text;
    Username = username;
    FirstName = txtFirstname.Text;
    LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    Email = txtEmail.Text;
    DateofBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dptDateofBirth.Value);
    PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
    Website = txtWebsite.Text;
    Town = txtTown.Text;
    Country = txtCountry.Text;
}
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //image upload
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    // HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadControl.UploadedFiles[i];
    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte[] imgByte = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    int imglength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    consultantProfile.ProfilePhoto = imgByte;
}
context.Entry(ConsultantsProfiles).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```